# Error: TypeError: Fx.Scroll is not a constructor

Tags: templates, joomla

i upgrade templete 2.5 to 3.0.

the Templete succesfully work bur some javascript error come.that are following.

Timestamp: 10/10/2013 10:34:36 AM
Error: TypeError: Fx.Scroll is not a constructor
Source File: libraries/gantry/js/gantry-totop.js
Line: 6

Answer (score 0):

Use **mootools-1.2.5.1-more.js**  
will be available in http://mootools.net/more125